# How can I reattach a ceramic towel bar end bracket to a ceramic tile wall?

Tags: bathroom, walls, ceramic-tile

the hanging frame on the wall of bath room was broken. If I want to fix myself, what are the tools/materials I should buy and what are the procedures?

As shown in the first figure, looks I need to use some materials that can attach the support to the wall. As shown in the second figure, the support on the left was good while the right one was broken, which need to be fixed. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the whole right bracket broken or is it OK and just let go from the wall?

Comment: Did it just fall off on it's own or was there some rambunctious activity in the shower?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that the towel bar may have been originally attached using tile grout. It should have been installed with tile *mortar*, and could have been grouted after the mortar was set. Mortar creates a much stronger bond.

Considering that you probably don't have mortar on hand, I'd swing by your local tile store and ask what they have in a small squeeze tube that would work. Otherwise, construction adhesive, pure silicone, or other household adhesives rated for moist areas would do as well.

You'll then want to caulk or grout around the base to help keep water out and create a finished appearance.

Comment: Hi, isherwood, thanks. So in the first picture, the materials are tile mortar, is that right? According to what you said, I need to first remove remaining mortar. Then re-install the bar with mortar. After that procedure, I need to grout it and caulk it. Is that right? Besides, how can I remove those mortar? Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove the bracket that is left if you dont have the other one.
2. Go to an hardware store look for an simmilar if not the same bracket, prefibly an set of two that contains the rod
3. Remove the old brackets and holders and install the new one
4. Post pictures if you are not sure how to below

Comment: "Buy one and put it up" doesn't really help here.